# "Incorrect string value" error in MySql when saving Unicode

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, utf-8

I was getting this error when I tried to add something like this `украден` to a group name field:

`(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD1\\x83\\xD0\\xBA\\xD1\\x80...' for column 'group_name' at row 1")`

At first, no group would was created if that error occurred. However, after I ran the MySql command that changes the encoding of the specific column where the error was occurring from `utf8` to `utf8_general_ci` on my django database, the group is created with the unicode characters I entered but the above error still gets displayed when I modify the group name using unicode characters.

Unicode method in models:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{}/{} (Group {})'.format(self.id, self.name,
                                      self.owner_group_id)
```

Comment: Have you defined a `__unicode__` method for the model? Are you making sure it returns Unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works for you, try and let me know if it works:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname')
cur = con.cursor()
con.set_character_set('utf8')
cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

Comment: Nope, that does not work. I think there is something wrong with your syntax.

Comment: try it again, I dropped `import MySQLdb as mdb`

Comment: No, I ran that on my SQL db but I am still getting the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though.